# Flickering visual artefacts and see-through windows after playing video in media player

Tags: windows-7, windows, 64-bit, graphics-card

I was watching a film using Windows Media Player on my secondary monitor whilst using Unity 3D on my primary monitor. This is something that I often do, however yesterday the video in Media Player went glittery and then the Unity editor also became corrupt with lines everywhere. After about 2 minutes my computer blue screened.

Here are the steps that I have taken so far:

- Restarted computer, same issue after bootup with just desktop showing
- Cold boot after being off for a while, same issue
- Took computer apart (all hardware) ensured that slots were free of dust and re constructed, same issue
- Ran memory diagnostics which passed

The visual artefacts are moving around my desktop each time a window is redrawn. This browser is flickering like crazy as I type. I have attached a screenshot of the problem. Not all visual artefacts were detected in screenshot, but it looks like some were (hard to tell).[image]

It is weird, as I type squares parts of this window reveal the desktop underneath.

Comment: Does it do it in safe mode?  What kind of video adapter is in question?

Comment: I've betting on an AMD card. You should download the latest drivers for your graphics card and reinstall them as a start.

Comment: Yep, the issue occurs in safe mode plus I have noticed it across the Windows starting logo. The issue is not noticeable in BIOS though. Yep (though just before they took ATI I believe). I have always been a big fan of ATI cards. It seems as though I am already running the latest drivers, but I have just reinstalled the drivers and the issue is still occurring (after restart).

Comment: My card is an ATI Radeon HD 2900 XT Pro (1GB version). I have just purchased the following to replace my card. I cannot believe that I have had my 2900 since 2007!  Time for an upgrade http://www.overclockers.co.uk/showproduct.php?prodid=GX-299-SP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, new graphics card works fine!

So I guess the old one just burnt out or something...